# How to export crystal repost directly to user instead of saving in project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

The question may be duplicate with the two below.

[sql server - How to export crystal report directly to pdf in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057841/how-to-export-crystal-report-directly-to-pdf-in-c-sharp-2010)

[asp.net - export crystal report to pdf without temp file programmatically in asp net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101986/export-crystal-report-to-pdf-without-temp-file-programmatically-in-asp-net)

My current code as below:

```cs
...
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
try
{
    rd.Load(Server.MapPath(string.Format("CrystalReport\\Example.rpt")));
    rd.SetDataSource(dt);
    DiskFileDestinationOptions doskOption = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
    rd.ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.ProtableDocFormat;
    rd.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
    string FileName = ...;
    disOption.DiskFileName = Server.MapPath("Report\\" + FileName + ".pdf");
    rd.ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = diskOption;
    rd.Export();
}
```

Use the code, everytime user click download as pdf, the crystal report will also save a copy in the project `Report` folder. And pop a new box ask user download or not, when user click the download, the browser start download.

Are there any methods to avoid save these temp files in my project. It waste a lot of useless space.
Or I have to clean the folder manually?

Answer (score 0):

The temporary file seems mandatory.

And I finally use js to check the box (which question users download or not) closed and execute delete the useless files.